# convert javascript code to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tags

I am new to this.
Please can someone help?

```js
< script type = 'text/javascript' >

  <!--//<![CDATA[

  document.MAX_ct0 = 'http://www.example.com';

var m3_u =

  (location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https://example.com/delivery/ajs.php?' : 'http://example.com/delivery/ajs.php?');

var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999);

document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + m3_u);

document.write("zoneid=54321");

document.write('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);

if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);

document.write(document.charset ? '&amp;charset=' + document.charset : (document.characterSet ?

  '&amp;charset=' + document.characterSet : ''));

document.write("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));

if (document.referrer) document.write("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));

if (document.context) document.write("&context=" + escape(document.context));

if ((typeof(document.MAX_ct0) != 'undefined') && (document.MAX_ct0.substring(0, 4) == 'http')) {

  document.write("&amp;ct0=" + escape(document.MAX_ct0));

}

if (document.mmm_fo) document.write("&amp;mmm_fo=1");

document.write("'></scr" + "ipt>");

//]]>--></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: convert the above code to an iframe tag

Comment: Can you be more specific? And `document.write` should be used only if you don't have other options (like in some cases of ad injections...)